# How to load first ActiveRecord Object automatically while working with AJAX partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of `@products` that appear in a table on `index.html.erb`. If you click on any one of the specific products, instead of going to a `show.html.erb` page, it issues an AJAX request and loads the `_show.html.erb` partial as expected on the `index.html.erb` page.

Is there a way to automatically load the first product to the `index.html.erb` page without having to click on the specific product using the AJAX request?

Right now, the `index.html.erb` page is blank in the area I render the partial until I click on a product, then it renders as expected. I am looking for the initial load of the `index.html.erb` page to load the first product.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I have 2 approaches.

Approach 1:
On `document.ready` send AJAX call for show of first product. So that it won't be an explicit click and the call will be like a lazy loading call.

Approach 2:
Simply modify your index code and render partial for first product in the area where you are expecting `_show.html.erb`
Something like following:

```
<%= render :partial => "show", :locals => { :product => @products.first }%>
# PRODUCT TABLE
<%- @products.each do |product| %>
  <% PRODUCT ROWS %>
<% end %>
```

Note: render partial syntax may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. Since I was able to have the AJAX request work as expected when I clicked the actual link to the product which rendered the `show` partial, adding a `script` tag on the `index` page allowed me to issue a `click` to the first product to accomplish the goal as well so that the `index` page did not initially render with no product.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() { $("#js-products a")[0].click(); }, 3000 );
</script>
```